# Display modal from another blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I display modal from another blade in the same directory laravel
Ihave this button to display the
**view**

```
@foreach
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applicantModal{{$applicant->applicants_id}}">View</a>
@endforech
```

and then I put this into the
**controller**

```
public function show()
{
      $applicants = Applicant::all();
      return view('applicant_list', compact('applicant'));
}
```

and then the
**modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="applicantModal{{$applicant->$applicants_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="applicantModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: include your modal file inside foreach...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal file lets say `abc.blade.php`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="applicantModal{{$applicant->$applicants_id}}" 
tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="applicantModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you have to add Modal file inside foreach loop.

```
@foreach
@include('path/to/your/modal/file/abc.blade.php');
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#applicantModal{{$applicant->applicants_id}}">View</a>
@endforech
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code use `compact('applicants')`

```
public function show()
{
      $applicants = Applicant::all();
      return view('applicant_list', compact('applicants'));
}
```

in your views try like this

```
@foreach($applicants as $applicant)
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applicantModal{{$applicant->applicants_id}}">View</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="applicantModal{{$applicant->$applicants_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="applicantModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

@endforech
```

Hope this helps.